# bash shell script terminates after program execution in loop

Tags: macos, bash, shell

The below simplified (printf/echo/cd/sleep/progressbar commands that do not matter left out) bash shell script terminates after the first execution of the binary. Why is this? Can I do or test anything without modifying the binary itself (Can only do this to certain limited extent) ?

```
PROGRESS=0
SIMULATIONS=30

for number in $(seq ${PROGRESS} ${SIMULATIONS})
  do
  echo 'INB4 TERMINATION'
  nohup ./binary -someflag
  # do other stuff next
  echo 'NEVER GETS HERE'
done
```

I have read up on `traps` but adding this line:

```
trap "echo 'trap invoked'; exit" SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM
```

- does not seem to work.
- Using `nohup` or not does not seem to matter.
- the loop works fine without the binary command.

**what the binary does**

It runs a 3D robot simulation experiment (which itself forks once to run 2 robot simulator processes in parallel (using the C/C++ system() command). Also each robot simulator launches a thread for each of 16 robot controllers). So the binary is the parent process of 32 threads. If that makes sense at all, does it matter?

Comment: Does the script launch the binary as expected? (At least the first time?)

Comment: Yes, it does, sorry forgot to add that. The binary does not throw any errors and (probably) finishes with exit status 0. I don't think I can check the exit status because my script quits right afterward, or should I be able to?

Comment: you can try adding inline `echo $?` right after your calling your script to check exit status: `nohup ./binary -someflag; echo $?`.

Comment: @MichaelTrouw *script quits* means the prompt will be displayed again?

Comment: You are using nohup but not running it in the background ?Try `command &`. Unless you are planning on exiting out of the script halfway through and leaving the binary running there is no need for `nohup`Also it looks like the binary never finished for whatever reason which is why your script doesn't continue. To check the binary actually finishes you can use `./binary && echo finished`. If it doesn't print finsihed on your screen then it hasn't.

Comment: @JID thanks will try this. I was using nohup solely for the 'no hanging up part' before in the original script, it's mainly an artifact but i can leave that out.

Comment: @JID the script DOES finish, the 'finished' echo comes right after: http://pastebin.com/DmHvL1CD

Comment: @JID how should i use the ```command &``` as you proposed?
like so? ```./binary -flags &``` ?

Comment: @ThomasHsieh it tells me the exit code is 0. So the binary does exit (successfully) but why my script does not continue, I have no idea...

Comment: What the hell. I just tried ```./binary -flags &```, which does continue the script, but now I see the prompt cursor flashing and nothing else happening: http://cl.ly/image/13453Z2m260H/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-07%20at%2013.02.26.png

So this leads me to think that it has to do with the binary... Can it be due to C++ system() calls or forking of the current process that change the parent process, or have the forked process finish last?

Comment: I have just confirmed that running the ```/.binary``` without flags (quits immediately) quits the loop as well, way before where the forking happens and way before the launching of ```system()``` calls happen.

Comment: @MichaelTrouw And you definitely have no breaks or if/thens anywhere after the binary runs ?Could be that a sigint (exit) in the c++ code is being propagated upwards. When you tried the trap where did you put it in the script ?

Comment: @JID sigh.. I just found out what was causing it. I pulled a progress bar bash function from somewhere and called that function after the ```./binary```. That was causing my script to stop. I just didn't thought it was the cause earlier, because it didn't output anything. That was a stupid assumption.

Comment: @MichaelTrouw ehh, atleast its fixed :)

Comment: @JID yeah :) thanks for the help! appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I just found out what was causing it. I pulled a progress bar bash function from somewhere and called that function after the ./binary. This was causing my script to stop... I just didn't thought it was the cause earlier, because it didn't output anything. That was a stupid assumption.

For completeness, this is the progress bar I was using:
https://github.com/fearside/ProgressBar/

Comment: This is part of why building a MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is important -- if you'd gone through the steps to build and test something that demonstrated the bug and contained no external dependencies (so other people could run it and see the problem for themselves -- and containing *nothing more than* the minimum necessary for that behavior), that process would have innately demonstrated where the issue was.